# Ruby equivalent to (JavaScript) Backbone

Tags: framework, web-apis, ruby

I am re-factoring a component service of an application, which is a JSON-over-HTTP microservice. The client and server are both Ruby.

Ideally the re-factored client code will produce model objects interchangeable with ORM objects from Sequel ORM, so that consumers of the higher-level model can be agnostic on what the data source/backing is.

I could write something based around [rest-client](https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) but am wondering if someone else has already solved this. When I search for "ruby rest client like backbone" I get tons of results for using Ruby/Rails *with* Backbone, so I am finding it hard to tell whether such a model-based RESTful client framework exists.

Desired features:

- Open-source Ruby gem.
- Consumes REST(ful) services and supports representation of them as a data model.

  - No need for clever consumption of interface-defining URIs
- DSL or declarative syntax for relationships between entities (probably *the* feature of backbone I'd like to replicate).

  - I am assuming that I have to write model code for each class, with a simple declarative-style DSL covering which fields to expose, how the object is read/written and how each relation needs to be followed according to the properties of the RESTful service.
- Simple caching/memoisation to prevent repeated requests when the client already has relevant data.
- Lightweight. Only has to cover simple basic relationships itself and allow custom methods when that is not possible.

  - Dependencies on e.g. `rest-client` are fine.
  - I have ruled out using a DataMapper model and DataMapper adaptors on this basis, and because the rest of the target application is moving to Sequel ORM.

---

Update:

Browsing rubygems, I have found [restfully](http://rubydoc.info/gems/restfully), [rest-core](https://github.com/godfat/rest-core), [rest_model](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest_model/0.3.1) and [arrest](http://rubydoc.info/gems/arrest/0.0.91). Although the last one seems quite light on documentation, they all seem to promise some of what I am looking for. Any experience or enlightenment on which best matches my requirements would be much appreciated.